# How to customise user profile fields in allauth after signup

Tags: django, django-allauth

I used allauth to signup function in my web application. In the socialaccount signup is collected from users e-mail, password, first and last name. In the sign in form I just collect e-mail and password from users.

Once logged, my app redirects the user to a profile page where is supposed to him/her update her profile (including new and customised fields, as the "institution" I added), if him/she wants to do so.

The question as a beginner in django-allauth, I'd like to know how to add these new customised fields to my user profile, and how to update those data once the user signed up.

what I did till now:

In settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
```

In my_project/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    institution = models.TextField(max_length=254)
```

In profile_page.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Profile Page{%endblock title%}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

{%block body%}

    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h1 class="text-center"><b>MY ONTOLOGIES</b></h1><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h1 class="text-center"><b>MY PROFILE</b></h1><br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label for="id_login" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-mail:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" id="asd" value="{{user.email}}" name="login"   class="form-control" required />
                        </div><br><br>
                        <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="id_first_name" value="{{user.first_name}}" name="first_name" class="form-control" required />
                        </div><br><br>
                        <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="id_last_name" value="{{user.last_name}}" name="last_name" class="form-control" required />
                        </div><br><br>
                        <label for="institution" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Institution:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="id_institution" value="{{user.institution}}" name="institution" class="form-control" placeholder="University/Company" required />
                        </div><br><br>
                        <label for="id_password1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Password:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" id="id_password1" name="password1" placeholder="New Password" type="password" />
                        </div><br><br>
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="id_password2">New Password (again):</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" id="id_password2" name="password2" placeholder="New Password (again)" type="password" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{%endblock body%}

{% endif %}
```

The code is clearly incomplete, because I didn't find a way to add the fields and save them properly as I requested. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem in two steps, and involve to refactor the code I post in my question:

1. First step (Create the custom field to user_table):

First of all I added an app to my project called CustomUser where I handle any issue related to allauth user.

in **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'CustomUser.apps.CustomuserConfig',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'CustomUser.CustomUser'
```

in **CustomUser/models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    add_your_custom_fields_here
```

in **CustomUser/apps.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.apps import AppConfig


class CustomuserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'CustomUser'
```

in CustomUser/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

After configuration your custom fields to the user table, you need to run the migrate command in shell to add these fields. In my case it didn't work, then I needed to flush my database and populate it again.

2. The second step is to create a updateform with the new user table.

First you need to override the User class from allauth. Creating a form.py in CustomUser folder we have:

from django import forms
from .models import CustomUser

```
class UpdateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        # Add here the fields you want to be present in the update form
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'institution')
```

in **CustomUser/templates/profile.html** you need to create the form for your app. In my case I created a primitive one:

```
Update your data <br><br>

<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

in **CustomUser/views.py** you're gonna configuration the behaviour of your profile.html page

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UpdateUserForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

def profile(UpdateView):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile/')
    else:
        form = UpdateUserForm()

    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form':form})

class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
        form_class = UpdateUserForm
        template_name = 'profile.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')

        #get object
        def get_object(self, queryset=None): 
            return self.request.user
```

Finally, just add the profile.html page to **urls.py** and voilà:

```
from CustomUser import views

url(r'^accounts/profile/$',  views.UserUpdate.as_view() , name='profile'),
```

Hope it helps someone... Thanks